# Como inserir dados em tempo de execução?

Tags: windows, batch, bat

Gostaria de escrever durante a execução de um arquivo bat.

Tenho  que digitar usuário e senha após executar um comando. Ao se executar o comando tenho a seguinte saída :

```
Você foi direcionado com sucesso.

Usernae =
```

Após o usuário digitar o username manualmente ele pede o password .

```
Você foi direcionado com sucesso.

Usernae = usuario

password =
```

Como posso criar um script  em batch para escrever esse usuário e senha sem que seja pedido para digitar ?

Comment: Você não tem como interagir com o terminal pelo script direto... O que eu acho que seria a solução é você checar se há uma forma de passar um parâmetro para esse seu script que você está executando que seja o usuário e a senha. Mais ou menos como o Mysql faz no CLI dele com o `-u` e `-p`

Comment: Já que você não quer digitar, os valores de usuário e senha do seu script seriam estáticos?

Comment: @AndréFilipe, de início sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Tenho alguns programas que usamos desenvolvidos em **FORTRAN**, sendo que não temos os códigos, e eles somente recebem os dados de entrada via digitação.
> >
> > Como não houve maneira para automatizar o recebimento de dados, (usamos muitos métodos sugeridos nas primeiras edições desta resposta), a solução foi usar o **VBS** para simular a digitação:
> >
> > **<kbd>`• Usando o VBS processando os dados de entrada num exemplo com 4 inputs:`</kbd>**
> >     **<kbd>`•  malha.dad, malha.log, n, n!`</kbd>**
> >
> > ### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> • Para portar esse código para seu cenário, apenas **substituir** nas linhas abaixo os **respectivos valores** para as **variáveis**:
>
> ***[_usuario_]  [_senha_]  [_exec_]***
>
> *set "_usuario_=**usuario-x**" & set "_senha_=**senha-y**"*
>
> *set "_exec_=**drive:\caminho\do\seu\executavel.exe**"*

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls

mode con cols=70 lines=20 & color 9F

set "_usuario_=usuario-x" & set "_senha_=senha-y" 

set "_exec_=drive:\caminho\do\seu\executavel.exe"

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrUser  = "!_usuario_!"
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_senha_!"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ for h=1 To Len^(StrUser^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrUser,h,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
    ) 

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" & cls && start "" /b "!_exec_!"

@"%Windir%\System32\cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" & del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```

Comment: Infelizmente esses comandos não serviram para mim . Preciso de uma maneira de enviar isso para o programa sem que seja necessário digitar e não posso mudar o programa pois é um executável de terceiro.

Comment: @Beto Boa tarde, mudei tudo na resposta, agora usando **bat** com **VBS**, e também foi testado com programa que solicita dados de entrada...

Answer (score 0):

Pode redirecionar a entrada de um arquivo.

Arquivo senha.cmd

```
@echo off

echo Lendo senha...
set /p senha=< senha.txt
echo Senha digitada: [%senha%]
```

Arquivo senha.txt

```
123
```

Rodando:

```
c:...> senha.cmd
Lendo senha...
Senha digitada: [123]
```